# Split a list into groups of consecutive elements based on a condition in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to group a list based on some type and if they are in sequence

```
data class Item(val type: Int, val name: String)

private fun splitItems(items: List<Item>): List<List<Item>> {
    val groupedItems = mutableListOf<List<Item>>()
    var tempList = mutableListOf<Item>()
    items.mapIndexed { index, item ->
        if (index > 0) {
            val previousItem = items[index - 1]
            if (previousItem.type == item.type) {
                tempList.add(item)
            } else {
                if (tempList.isNotEmpty()) groupedItems.add(tempList)
                tempList = mutableListOf()
                tempList.add(item)
            }
        } else tempList.add(item)
    }
    if (tempList.isNotEmpty()) groupedItems.add(tempList)
    return groupedItems
}
```

Now this fun will take

```
val items = mutableListOf(
    Item(1, "Shirt"),
    Item(1, "Shirt"),
    Item(2, "Pant"),
    Item(2, "Pant"),
    Item(2, "Pant"),
    Item(1, "Shirt"),
    Item(1, "Shirt"),
    Item(3, "Tee"),
    Item(3, "Tee"),
    Item(2, "Pant"),
    Item(2, "Pant"),
    Item(1, "Shirt"),
    Item(1, "Shirt"),
    Item(1, "Shirt")
)
```

and return

```
[Item(type=1, name=Shirt), Item(type=1, name=Shirt)]
[Item(type=2, name=Pant), Item(type=2, name=Pant), Item(type=2, name=Pant)]
[Item(type=1, name=Shirt), Item(type=1, name=Shirt)]
[Item(type=3, name=Tee), Item(type=3, name=Tee)]
[Item(type=2, name=Pant), Item(type=2, name=Pant)]
[Item(type=1, name=Shirt), Item(type=1, name=Shirt), Item(type=1, name=Shirt)]
```

This is working as expected. Since I am trying to learn Kotlin and I know there is a beautiful way of doing this, I would like to know how I can simplify this logic in kotlin way.

Comment: Use a HashMap with the type as key and ArrayList<Item> as value.

Comment: May I ask what your use case is for this? Usually we would use `groupBy` or similar utilities, but it won't preserve the "sequence" information in the result. So I'm wondering why you need this data structure as output.

Comment: Actually the items are sorted based on time and I need to retain the sequence

Comment: Another approach might be to use [`fold()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/fold.html).  (Sorry, don't have time to write something now; there are probably examples in previous questions.  Or it would make an instructive exercise :-)

Answer (score 3):

Short And Simple Pure Kotlin way

```
   val result = items.fold(ArrayList<ArrayList<Item>>()) { list, item -> list.apply {
        if (isEmpty() || last().last().type != item.type)
            add(arrayListOf(item))
        else
            last().add(item)
        }
    }
    println(result)
```

Result

```
[[Item(type=1, name=Shirt), Item(type=1, name=Shirt)], [Item(type=2, name=Pant), Item(type=2, name=Pant), Item(type=2, name=Pant)], [Item(type=1, name=Shirt), Item(type=1, name=Shirt)], [Item(type=3, name=Tee), Item(type=3, name=Tee)], [Item(type=2, name=Pant), Item(type=2, name=Pant)], [Item(type=1, name=Shirt), Item(type=1, name=Shirt), Item(type=1, name=Shirt)]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a succinct and efficient way to do it with imperative code. I can't think of a pure functional solution from the standard library that would be as efficient. In my opinion, using `fold` and then internally manipulating multiple lists and treating the first item as a special case is not as readable, nor is it as performant.

```
fun <T, C> Iterable<T>.chunkedByConsecutive(comparisonSelector: (T) -> C): List<List<T>> {
    if (none()) return emptyList()
    val lists = mutableListOf<MutableList<T>>()
    var previous: C? = null
    for (item in this) {
        if (previous != comparisonSelector(item).also { previous = it } || lists.isEmpty()) {
            lists += mutableListOf(item)
        } else {
            lists.last() += item
        }
    }
    return lists
}
```

Answer (score 1):

<sup>*This is the original answer with the original solution. For a better (imo) implementation, scroll to the EDIT*</sup>

[Different approaches are chosen for the grouping functionality by different languages](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p2214r0.html#the-group_by-family).

Some languages, like Kotlin, take the approach of implementing `groupBy` by taking a unary **function** `(T) -> U` and returning a dictionary that maps every `U` to a list of `T`s that mapped to it. Other languages, like Haskell, work with `(T, T) -> Boolean` **predicates** that group *consecutive elements* that satisfy the predicate.

No functionality in Kotlin supports conveniently such operation that you desire to use. Because of that, you have to implement your own. A slightly shorter code than yours would be:

```
fun <T> Iterable<T>.groupConsecutiveBy(predicate: (T, T) -> Boolean): List<List<T>> {
    var leftToGroup = this.toList()
    val groups = mutableListOf<List<T>>()

    while (leftToGroup.isNotEmpty()) {
        val firstItem = leftToGroup[0]
        val newGroup = leftToGroup.takeWhile { predicate(it, firstItem) }
        groups.add(newGroup)
        leftToGroup = leftToGroup.subList(newGroup.size, leftToGroup.size)
    }

    return groups
}
```

and call it like:

```
fun main() {
    val items = mutableListOf(
        Item(1, "Shirt"),
        Item(1, "Shirt"),
        Item(2, "Pant"),
        Item(2, "Pant"),
        Item(2, "Pant"),
        Item(1, "Shirt"),
        Item(1, "Shirt"),
        Item(3, "Tee"),
        Item(3, "Tee"),
        Item(2, "Pant"),
        Item(2, "Pant"),
        Item(1, "Shirt"),
        Item(1, "Shirt"),
        Item(1, "Shirt")
    )
    
    items.groupConsecutiveBy{ left, right -> left.type == right.type }.also(::print)
}
```

which would yield:

> ```
> [[Item(type=1, name=Shirt), Item(type=1, name=Shirt)], [Item(type=2, name=Pant), Item(type=2, name=Pant), Item(type=2, name=Pant)], [Item(type=1, name=Shirt), Item(type=1, name=Shirt)], [Item(type=3, name=Tee), Item(type=3, name=Tee)], [Item(type=2, name=Pant), Item(type=2, name=Pant)], [Item(type=1, name=Shirt), Item(type=1, name=Shirt), Item(type=1, name=Shirt)]]
> ```

We are using na extension method for an `Iterable` of any `T` here. This is the idiomatic way of introducing such functionality in Kotlin, because it's an operation that will be done *by* any `Iterable`. I also made it generic (`T`) and to accept any `predicate` that will be tested with consecutive elements.

---

EDIT: Actually, there is a functionality that accumulates every single element one by one to a certain structure. It's sometimes called *accumulate*, *reduce* or, in Kotlin, *`fold`*:

```
fun <T> Iterable<T>.groupConsecutiveBy(groupIdentifier: (T, T) -> Boolean) =
    if (!this.any())
        emptyList()
    else this
        .drop(1)
        .fold(mutableListOf(mutableListOf(this.first()))) { groups, t ->
            groups.last().apply {
                if (groupIdentifier.invoke(last(), t)) {
                    add(t)
                } else {
                    groups.add(mutableListOf(t))
                }
            }
            groups
        }
```

This is a single expression which is, arguably, even more idiomatic than the previous one. It uses no raw loops and holds no state in between code parts. It's also very simple - either the `Iterable` in question is empty and, in that case, we return an empty list, or, in case of elements present, we fold them into a list of groups (`List` of `List`s).

Note the `drop(1)` - we do that because we `fold` all elements into the final list that already contains that element (by construction in the `fold()` call). By doing that we save ourselves from introducing additional checks for the emptiness of the list.

Answer (score -2):

You should use partition.

```
val array = intArrayOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
val (even, odd) = array.partition { it % 2 == 0 }
println(even) // [2, 4]
println(odd) // [1, 3, 5]
```

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/partition.html

Comment: This is just for splitting into two.