# Partitioning consecutive elements of a list based on a predicate in functional style

Tags: kotlin, lambda, functional-programming

I need to implement a function in Kotlin:

```
fun <T> partitionConsecutiveWithPredicate(input : List<T>, pred : (T, T) -> Boolean) : List<List<T>>
```

The function partitions the input list into a list of lists when every sub-list in the resulting list is a group of consecutive elements from the original list which conform to the provided predicate.

Example #1 - invoking the method on the Int list of
`[2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 8, 2, 2, 3]`
with the predicate `{ t1 : Int, t2 : Int -> t1 == t2}`
should result in `[[2, 2, 2, 2], [5, 5], [8], [2, 2], [3]]`

Example #2 - invoking the method on the Int list of
`[1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2]`
with the predicate `{ t1 : Int, t2 : Int -> t2 == t1 + 1}`
should result in `[[1, 2, 3, 4], [3], [2], [1, 2]]`

Naturally, I can achieve that with a traditional while-loop and list manipulation library functions, but I want to do it in a purely functional style, i.e. only using lambdas/sequences (no explicit for/while loops allowed).
I tried using runningReduce and runningFold, but it creates a resulting list in every step, which isn't desirable in this case (you should create a sub-list only when the predicate stops being satisfied).

---

**EDIT:** It's been brought to my attention that a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65355091/split-a-list-into-groups-of-consecutive-elements-based-on-a-condition-in-kotlin) exists, but said question doesn't emphasize the need for a functional solution, therefore I'm leaving this one as is.

Comment: Is this an exercise, or for production?  It's almost certainly _possible_ with a fold-type call — though you might need to do something like zipWithNext() first so you can tell when to start a new sublist.  But I suspect it would be simpler and more maintainable in an imperative style with a while loop…

Comment: It's an exercise. No constraints were imposed with regards to the implementation (imperative/functional), but I wanted to try the functional way, as the imperative one is pretty straightforward.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split a list based on condition in kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65355091/split-a-list-based-on-condition-in-kotlin) This question does not have "consecutive" in the title, but should have. Will edit it shortly. I believe it's pretty much an exact duplicate.

Comment: @Fureeish see edit

Comment: @KidCrippler but the final snippet of code from my answer there is basically a single expression that pretty much fully functional. What is not functional there? What in that answer is lacking?

Comment: @Fureeish you're right. How should we move forward now?

Comment: Well, if that question covers what is inside your question and that answer answers your questions, I'd suggest accepting the duplicate flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be better ways of doing it, one way is using a loop:

```
fun <T> partitionConsecutiveWithPredicate2(input: List<T>, pred: (T, T) -> Boolean): List<List<T>> {
    val result = mutableListOf<List<T>>()
    var currentList = mutableListOf<T>()
    input.forEachIndexed { i, el ->
        currentList.add(el)
        if (i + 1 >= input.size || !pred(el, input[i + 1])) {
            result.add(currentList.toList())
            currentList = mutableListOf()
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

The idea here is to accumulate the values in the `currentList` until all the elements have been processed (`i + 1 >= input.size`) or the predicate is not fulfilled in which case the currentList is added to the result and emptied.

Executable code in kotlin playground: https://pl.kotl.in/rv_Yq8WdG with functional and iterative versions.

Or use [fold](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/fold.html):

```
fun <T> partitionConsecutiveWithPredicate(input: List<T>, pred: (T, T) -> Boolean)
    = input
        .fold(mutableListOf()) { acc: MutableList<MutableList<T>>, elem ->
            when {
                acc.lastOrNull() == null -> acc.add(mutableListOf(elem))
                acc.lastOrNull() != null -> acc.last().apply {
                    if (pred(last(), elem)) {
                        add(elem)
                    } else {
                        acc.add(mutableListOf(elem))
                    }
                }
            }
            acc
        }
```

Executable code in kotlin playground:
https://pl.kotl.in/z_ccIgX5C

Comment: Thanks! This is an elegant solution, but not so functional, as you could replace the `mapIndexed` call with a loop and that's pretty much the imperative solution.

Comment: OK, I've also added another version using fold