# Split list into groups based on predicate in kotlin

Tags: list, kotlin

Given for example the following :

`val l = listOf(1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2)`, I'd like to have `l2 = [ [1], [2, 2, 2, 2], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2]]`.
I'd accept something in the lines of `l2 = [ (1, 1), (2, 4), (1, 3), (2, 2)]`, whichever is the fastest to achieve.

Separating the lists into groups should be based on a predicate ( a function taking a value and returning a boolean).

I've been looking into the cleanest way to split a list into groups based on predicate in kotlin. I've found quite a few different ways to split a list (chunked, groupBy, ...) but nothing that quite matches what I need.

I know it is possible to do it using a loop, but I'd rather to do it FP style. What's the cleanest way you can come up with? Extra points for using utilities of the standard library.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't you think, custom collector impl. can do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split a list into groups of consecutive elements based on a condition in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65355091/split-a-list-into-groups-of-consecutive-elements-based-on-a-condition-in-kotlin)

Comment: Looks like it, thanks a lot!