# How can I use elegant kotlin techniques to solve this problem? (FP)

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming

I have a kotlin problem, can you come up with a elegant way of solving it?

so effectively I have a list of Journeys which could be by car or not, I want to find where there are consecutive car journeys in a list; i.e. 2 or more cars in a row in the list. Then from these chains of consecutive cars I wan to sum the mileage per chain and print out the maximum. This is the data class

```
  data class Journey(
    val isCar: Boolean = false,
    val mileage: Int,
  )
```

Here is an example list of journeys. So in this example the correct answer should be 80, because there are two consecutive entries with 40+40 as the mileage. That beats the only other consecutive entry of 10+20=30. The rest are single car journeys and non car journeys so are ignored.

```
listOf(
      Journey(true, 10),
      Journey(true, 20),
      Journey(false, 105),
      Journey(true, 1046),
      Journey(false, 130),
      Journey(true, 40),
      Journey(true, 40),
    )
```

My solution is below, however it's very ugly and non-functional. Can you solve this in an elegant way using modern functional techniques without mutable Lists? Thanks

```
val journeys = listOf(
      Journey(true, 10),
      Journey(true, 20),
      Journey(false, 105),
      Journey(true, 1046),
      Journey(false, 130),
      Journey(true, 40),
      Journey(true, 40),
    )

    val cars = journeys.filter { it.isCar }
    val journeysByIndex = cars.map { journeys.indexOf(it) to it  }
    val consecutiveJourneys = mutableListOf<MutableList<Journey>>()

    journeysByIndex.forEach {
      if (consecutiveJourneys.any { cj1 -> cj1.any { cj2 -> cj2 == it.second  } }) {
        return@forEach
      }
      val journeyList = mutableListOf(it.second)
      var index = it.first
      var nextJourneyExists = true
      while (nextJourneyExists) {
        var journey: Journey? = null
        if ((index + 1) < journeys.size  && journeys[index + 1].isCar) {
          journey = journeys[index+1]
        }
        nextJourneyExists = if (journey!= null) {
          journeyList.add(journey)
          true
        } else {
          false
        }
        index += 1
      }
      consecutiveJourneys.add(journeyList)
    }

    var maxAmountForConsecutive = consecutiveJourneys.filter {it.size > 1 }.map{ it.sumOf {cs -> cs.mileage}}.max()

    println("max1: " + maxAmountForConsecutive)
```

Comment: Grouping consecutive elements by a predicate [has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65355091/split-a-list-into-groups-of-consecutive-elements-based-on-a-condition-in-kotlin). No super elegant looking way to do it. But once you’ve done that, the rest is straightforward. You can do `map { it.sumBy(Journey::mileage) }.maxOrNull() ?: 0`

Comment: Thanks @Tenfour04, I didn't know about fold. I think that will massively improve it. Will upload a neater solution with fold tomorrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the grouping method that Tenfour04 suggested in the comment, which I personally find a bit overkill for a task like this (but it is useful in other scenarios), you could also just simply count.

We can create a simple extension function that counts each step, then resets once it hits a `isCar:false`:

```kotlin
fun Collection<Journey>.calculateMaxByCarConsecutive(): Int {
    var max = 0
    var currentMileageSum = 0
    var count = 0

    forEach { current ->
        if (current.isCar) {
            //if the current journey is in a car, add its mileage to our current count
            currentMileageSum += current.mileage
            //increase count that tells us how many journeys have been consecutive
            count++

            //if we have more than 1 journey creating the currentMileageSum 
            //and 
            //currentMileageSum is greater than max, 
            // then the currentMileageSum becomes the new max
            if (count > 1) max = maxOf(currentMileageSum, max)
        } else {
            //reset the counters if this record is not by car
            count = 0
            currentMileageSum = 0
        } 
    }

    return max
}
```

Then we can call it like this:

```
val journeys = listOf(
    Journey(true, 10),
    Journey(true, 20),
    Journey(true, 40),
    Journey(false, 105),
    Journey(true, 10423423),
    Journey(false, 130),
    Journey(true, 40),
    Journey(true, 40),
    Journey(true, 10),
)

val maxJourneyByCar = journeys.calculateMaxByCarConsecutive()

println(maxJourneyByCar) //this will print 90
```

Not sure if this is more elegant that your solution or than using fold, but I do think it is simpler.

Comment: Does the example I posted work with your solution? The answer should be 80 for my example.

Comment: yes, it does, it should work with any sample

Comment: you are supposed to be ignoring single car journeys. Only sum where a consecutive chain exists. Use my example

Comment: @Storms786 I didn't notice that part, still quite simple, I've modified the answer and added a count that checks how many consecutive journeys created the current mileage, the `currentMileageSum` only becomes `max` when we have more than 1 consecutive `isCar`. Also renamed `currentCount` to `currentMileageSum`, since the name wasn't that good.

Comment: Thanks @Alex.T - that's quite neat and certainly better than mine. I'm gonna give it a day or so and if no one comes up with a more elegant way I'll accept your answer